# Increase the amount of vote to close flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close

You get a flat rate of 50 vote to close flags per day.
Most of the time between 25 and 35 are used when I am dealing with the Close Votes queue and another 5 or 10 could be used while doing the Low Quality Posts queue.
While using SO I would come across other questions that need to be closed (unclear what is being asked/are a duplicate etc.), but end up not being able to because I have used up all the close flags for the day and have to make a note of the posts and deal with them the next day.

Where as for the flag votes you start with 10 and it can increase to 100 (if the reported posts are correct).

I am wondering would it be possible to increase the 50 votes to close as the flag votes increase as well? Or would it not be worth the hassle to implement this because it wouldn't effect that many people?

Comment: Delete votes scale with reputation, so I don't see why close votes are any different.

Comment: My tip - review at the end of the day. Then you tend to not feel the close vote limit as much.

Comment: But then you would end up seeing reviews that should be closed but can't because you don't have any more votes.